# What is the physical location of Blockchain?

Tags: database, blockchain, ethereum

Hello everyone i am new in this technology and i am confused please clear my few doubts. Thanks in advance.

1. Blockchain consist of Blocks but where these blocks are stored, i mean what is the **physical location of Blocks**.
2. As per my theoretical knowledge blockchain exist in network but in which network, do we need to create our own network or is there any third party those who provide network for our application.
3. Suppose i have to develop land registry application i need some space somewhere where i can store my blocks. if i store all block in my system itself then how it will behave like a decentralized.
4. Does Ethereum stored our blocks in his network?
5. Blockchain itself is a database but how we can manage the data.
6. Does BigchainDB stored our blocks or blockchain in his database?

Answer (score 3):

1. Blockchain is shared among all the p2p network hosting it. So basically blockchain is stored in many simple HDD all around the world.
2. If you want to create a totally new blockchain, you create your own network. If you want, for example, to use Ethereum network to run your token, then you'll use Ethereum network (which has been created for Ethereum at the first place)
3. That's what the blockchain and it's protocol do. Store datas in multiple places and handle the integrity and safety of the datas. You need to have multiple agents in your network to be decentralized. You alone is centralized.
4. Yes, or more exactly, Ethereum users store datas in their storages for the Ethereum network
5. You can imagine different form of blockchain, but speaking about the first one, Bitcoin, when the p2p network is launched and used, you can't manage datas by yourself. The network will handle it, and the only way you can manage datas is by having more than 50% of the mining power (in an other way the network let users manage datas in an normal use case, for exemple, send your bitcoin is a normal use case, steal someone is not)
6. Sorry, I never heard about it =/

To others: Feel free to modify my answer as you please, I'm not an expert, just trying to share and perfect my knowledge

Comment: It's a little better to describe it as storing your transactions on the blockchain. A block consists of multiple transactions that have been verified by the mining process. The transactions within an individual block don't have to be related (and almost always are not related in the public blockchain). To expand on #2 a bit, you are not required to create a private network to launch your dApp. Some common use cases for creating a private network are to have different environments for dev/QA, or for security reasons so you can control who mines your transactions.

Comment: Just to add to this, I think it might be worth while to mention that a Block isnt a physical thing, until its written to disk.  Theoretically, you wouldnt even need physical storage if your network had 100% uptime.  The blocks are an object created by the blockchain application, and we store them on disk to address persistence.

Comment: Your datas, blockchain or not, always end in a physical storage. Be it your RAM, a SSD, an HDD, or whatever you want. So yes, it could stay out of HDD, but you would need a very big RAM, or a very very very very good connection to send the entire blockchain in a blink each time a new block is mined